# SharePoint 2013 how to move folder and its all content from one location to another location

Tags: java, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How to move the folder and its all content from one location to another location.

With the following code, I have successfully moved a file but I could not able to  move the folder
it gives and error response like

```
<ErrorCode>UNKNOWN</ErrorCode>

<ErrorText>Value does not fall within the expected range.</ErrorText>
```

I tried code from https://www.javaworld.com/article/2078906/java-tip-consuming-sharepoint-web-services-with-a-java-client.html?page=2

```
  DestinationUrlCollection destinationUrlCollection = new DestinationUrlCollection();
       destinationUrlCollection.getString().add("some URL");


        FieldInformation titleFieldInformation = new FieldInformation();
        titleFieldInformation.setType(FieldType.TEXT);
        titleFieldInformation.setValue("some value");

        FieldInformationCollection fields = new FieldInformationCollection();
        fields.getFieldInformation().add(titleFieldInformation);

        CopyResultCollection results = new CopyResultCollection();
        Holder resultHolder = new Holder(results);
        Holder longHolder = new Holder();

        //make the call to upload
        copySoap.copyIntoItems(sourceUrl, destinationUrlCollection, fields, bytearray, longHolder,resultHolder);
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you didn't know there is tool called [Sharepoint Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool).
In my case, wether its file/folder transfer from a file storage or another sharepoint site it transfers all of the contents of the source folder to the destination.
It also preserves all user permissions on each folder.

Comment: If you really must use Java then use either the REST API or the list data service